# ENOTCACHED error when deploying with npm in offline environment

Tags: node.js, npm, deployment, offline

My deployment environment is in an air-gapped datacentre; there's no physical connection to the World Wide Web. Our system is installed with NodeJS 18 and the corresponding NPM 9. During the initial deployment, we:

1. Downloaded the latest versions of dependencies with npm on an Internet-facing machine.
2. Transferred the packages across the air gap into the local repository (there's no offline registry in the approved system architecture).
3. Deployed the application into production.
4. Removed development dependencies (which were needed for compiling the application in the production machine) using `npm prune --omit=dev`

That was back in November. Today, we attempted to demonstrate the deployment process to the O&S team, using the same `node_modules` downloaded in Nov 2023, but hit some unexpected snags in the last step. After some research and troubleshooting, we configured npm to offline mode:

```
npm config set audit=false offline=true prefer-offline=true
```

We attempted to run `npm prune --omit=dev` again, only to run into a new error which I can't understand. The error message is roughly like so (words in both are verbatim):

> npm ERR! code **ENOTCACHED**
>
> npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/something-something
> failed: **cache mode is 'only-if-cached' but no cached response
> available.**

My current understanding of the issue is that NPM considers the `node_modules` downloaded in Nov to be stale in the present day and is thus attempting to refresh the stale data by connecting to the Internet. This obviously fails as there's no existing connection, nor will there be any. The offline-mode configuration we just added to NPM worked to an extent, since the previous issues were resolved, but that somehow wasn't enough to prevent NPM from making a connection attempt in the current issue.

Setting up an offline npm registry isn't possible for out-of-scope and not-in-contract reasons. We are also hoping to avoid regular patch updating: the O&S team is only contracted to perform ad-hoc patching in response to security vulnerabilities, so something like monthly updating isn't paid for presently. Not to mention the immense amount of red tape in approving regularly transfers of such data volumes across the air gap.

How do I get NPM to just do as it's asked - prune dev dependencies from `node_modules` - and not check the Internet for any reason whatsoever? The `package.json` and `package-lock.json` should've all the information it needs.